# Linux Mint 20 (systemd networkd) is ignoring dhclient.conf by not calling dhclient (isc-dhcp client)

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, dhcp, systemd

I'm running Linux Mint 20 "Ulyana" and when it boots it seems to completely ignore `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

In previous versions of Linux Mint, one could add the following line to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.1.125;
```

and when Linux Mint would boot up it would call `dhclient` (isc-dhcp client) which by default would make use of `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` as default config file.

While invoking `dhclient` by hand once Linux mint has boot up seems to work fine, that's not an acceptable solution:

```
sudo -i
dhclient -v -4 -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf -pf /run/dhclient.eno1.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eno1.leases
```

It looks like in previous versions, Linux Mint's systemd-networkd, systemd-dispatcher or NetworkManager would call `dhclient` but not it is not happening anymore.

Do someone know how could I fix or workaround this issue?

In the end **I would like to pass some extra request parameters to the DHCP server**. Mainly, **I would like to ask for a defined IP address**, ie: 192.168.1.125.

Those are the systemd network related services which seem to be running

```
networkd-dispatcher. service loaded active running
networking.service loaded active exited
NetworkManager loaded active running
network.target loaded active active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd-networkd has *never* used dhclient; it has its own DHCP client library built in.

NetworkManager supports multiple DHCP clients. The default depends on your distro (and NM version), but it can be changed via `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` in the `[main]` section.

- `dhcp=dhclient` runs the standalone dhclient program.
- `dhcp=internal` uses a built-in client (either the sd-dhcp library copied from systemd-networkd, or the nettools/n-dhcp4 library, depending on NM version).
- `dhcp=systemd` uses a built-in client (the sd-dhcp library).
- `dhcp=nettools` uses a built-in client (the nettools/n-dhcp4 library).

(Note that NetworkManager *never* uses the standalone systemd-networkd service – it just has parts of the networkd code embedded directly.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's very clearful. I'm very confused about all the systemd network service run at boot. Would you mind telling me briefly, what's each service used for and how could I check which service is the one which manages my network config?